# What is the most suited language to implement this DSL?

Tags: function, hash, lambda, language-design, dsl

I would like to program a DSL with a very short syntax for two things I noticed to be very essential to programming, functions and hashes. This is my design:

Creates a hash:

```
(a:1 b:2 c:3)
Same as JavaScript's: {a:1,b:2,c:3}
```

Creates ordered hash, omitting keys:

```
(x y 5) 
Same as JavaScript's: {0:'x', 1:'y', 2:5}
```

Creates an anonymous function:

```
(a?)
Same as JavaScript's: (function(x){ return x.a; })
Example application:
    ((test a? b?) (a:1 b:2 c:3))
    >> Outputs (test 1 2)
```

Nested functions:

```
(a? a?') 
Same as JavaScript's: (function(obj1){ return function(obj2) { return [obj1.a,obj2.a]; }; })
Example double-application:
    (((a? a?') (a:1)) (a:2))
    Is reduced to: ((1 a?) (a:2))
    Then outputs: (1 2)
```

What language is suited for the implementation of such DSL?

Comment: How exactly do you want to execute such a program? Do you want to compile it into an executable binary, interpret it with some interpreter or transform your programs into some other programming language and let it be executed there?

Comment: The last option, or something like it. I would be like to implement some kind of 'short fundamental' in which I could then make my language easy injectable in any environment, like C++, JavaScript. I'm not sure this is possible, so, any target is OK, I guess? Just any language which would make it easiest to implement my own syntax would be fine.

Comment: To implement your own syntax, you most probably need to write your own preprocessor for the language + your additions, which transforms your program into the target language. Since Javascript simplifications seem to be what you have in mind, you should go for that... As a starting point, you could take a grammar for Javascript for some parser generator and add your constructs to it. Another try would be to (mis-)use some languages constructs to behave like you want. C++ and its functional operator comes to my mind here.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds a lot like you'd like a language with a powerful macro system, like some kind of Scheme. Macros allow for exactly this kind of syntax extension, where fragments of code from the original language can be embedded into the new forms that you propose (I assume you want to be able to say `(a:1+1  b:2*2)`, etc.). Furthermore, a macro system doesn't complicate your build process or destroy error message locations, the way an external preprocessor does.

But there's bad news, which is that there aren't any (non-esoteric) languages I know of that have enough room in their syntax to provide the exact syntax that you specify.

Here's the syntax that I came up with:

Hash:

```lisp
(: a 1 b 2 c 3)
; or, more clearly
(: (a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

Index-keyed hash:

```lisp
(:lst 'x 'y 5)
```

(if you allow barewords on the RHS of a hash, you're going to have a tough time referencing variables, so I assumed you didn't want that)

Anonymous attribute-accessing function:

```lisp
(anon. a)
```

Like the former, but taking multiple arguments by currying them and then returning a list:

```lisp
(anon. a a)
```

The good news is that you don't need to write a lexer or parser or muck around with the build system to add this syntax to Scheme; it's just a few lines of code, and importing syntax is just like importing functions.

The first macro (named `:`) is dead simple to write:

```lisp
(define-syntax-rule (: (k v) ...)
  (make-hash `((k ,v) ...)))
```

The second one (named `:lst`) is harder, since you need to generate the indices. It'd probably be under ten lines of code, but I'm too lazy to write them...

The third macro (`anon.`) is a little non-trivial, but sort of fun, so here it is:

```lisp
(define-syntax anon.
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((anon. attr attrs ...) 
       (lambda (x) (cons (hash-ref x 'attr) (anon. attrs ...) )))
      ((anon.)
        empty)))
```

(Note that I've assumed, for the sake of consistency, that you want `anon.` to always return a list; doing otherwise would require adding an extra clause to `syntax-rules` for the special case.) I'm not sure that `anon.` would really be a useful macro, but that's between you and your codebase.

If you want to hack with macros, I'd suggest you try out my favorite Scheme flavor, [Racket](http://racket-lang.org). It has a particularly macro-oriented world view (see [this blog post](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2007/05/macros-matter.html), written back when Racket was called "PLT Scheme").